# How to set up Stylelint in a Next.js project?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, next.js, stylelint

I want to add [Stylelint](https://stylelint.io/) to my Next.js app. I am asking if I can edit `next.config.js` to add [stylelint-webpack-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/stylelint-webpack-plugin/), so I get styles errors during compilation.

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Prepare the setup for both CSS and SCSS

1. Install needed packages:

```
npm i stylelint stylelint-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

2. Create a `.stylelintignore` file in your root folder et past in it:

```
node_modules
```

3. Edit the `next.config.js` file:

```js
const StylelintPlugin = require("stylelint-webpack-plugin"); // line to add
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  // lines to add
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.plugins.push(new StylelintPlugin());
    return config;
  },

};
```

### Set up Stylelint with CSS

1. Install the needed package:

```
npm i stylelint-config-standard --save-dev
```

2. Create a `.stylelintrc` file in your root folder and past in it:

```json
{
 "extends": "stylelint-config-standard",
 "rules": {
   "string-quotes": "double"
  }
}
```

### Set up Stylelint with SCSS

1. Install needed packages:

```
npm i sass stylelint-config-standard-scss --save-dev
```

2. Create a `.stylelintrc` file in your root folder and past in it:

```json
{
 "extends": "stylelint-config-standard-scss",
 "rules": {
   "string-quotes": "double"
  }
}
```